# How to attribute goal conversions to a user landing on the site from a Twitter link

Tags: twitter, conversions, goals

I have a client who posts links to their ecommerce site on their twitter profile throughout the week. users click those links that takes them to the ecommerce site, and they will purchase a product. I already have the goal of a successful order checkout as a destination URL. How would I add the layer of someone landing on site from twitter to the goal path?

Twitter link-->user clicks twitter link-->goes to ecommerce site-->order-checkout-success destination URL

Comment: You should tag the twitter link with UTM parameters so that you can attribute your goals to the correct source of traffic.

Comment: what if client doesn't ever use proper utms in their links?

Comment: Have the client start using UTM params.   You can also set them on the website based on referrer if you can do some JavaScript coding.

Comment: can you link me to any examples of the option to set them on website based on referrer? i would assume some javascript that determines referrer, then adds params to url? but would that effect htaccess? anyway, any help explaining that point would be helpful

Comment: It doesn't need to change the URL.   JavaScript that calls the GA tracker directly: `ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'Announcements'); ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'TwitterLinks');`: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference

Answer (score 1):

Try the following report, it should show you your data split up by Source/Medium and allow you to analyze eCommerce/Goal data with the dropdown on the right.

The entry 'Twitter / referral' should be there in the list.

`Acquisition > All Traffic > Source/Medium`